# How run custom https domain in dart?

Tags: dart

I got some troubles, when try run dart server with SSL. Dart VM version - 1.24.3. Apache or other services disables. I mean `443` and `80` ports are free. SSL certs from letsencrypt

In `main.dart` file:

```
import 'dart:io';
import "dart:isolate";

main() {
  SecurityContext context = new SecurityContext();
  var fullchain = Platform.script.resolve('/home/user/.ssl/turarabu/www/fullchain.pem').toFilePath();
  var privkey   = Platform.script.resolve('/home/user/.ssl/turarabu/www/privkey.pem').toFilePath();

  context.useCertificateChain(fullchain);
  context.usePrivateKey(privkey);

  HttpServer
      .bindSecure('www.turarabu.com', 443, context)
      .then((server) {
        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
          request.response.write('Hello, world!');
          request.response.close();
        });
      });
}
```

In `/etc/hosts` file

```
35.198.81.101 www.turarabu.com
```

But when I try run:

```
sudo dart main.dart
```

Got this error:

```
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Cannot assign requested address, errno = 99), address = www.turarabu.com, port = 443
#0      _NativeSocket.bind.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:511)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1371)
#2      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129)
#3      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:636)
#4      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:665)
#5      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:478)
#6      _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:510)
#7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50)
#9      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:99)
#10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:152)
```

ifconfig output

```
ens4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:9c:00:03
          inet addr:10.156.0.3  Bcast:10.156.0.3  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::4001:aff:fe9c:3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:708175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:6
          TX packets:629464 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:247043081 (247.0 MB)  TX bytes:76546648 (76.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5065 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:5065 (5.0 KB)
```

What I do wrong?

P.S. `main.dart` and SSL files chmod permiossions are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the output of `ifconfig`? In particular, can you confirm that one of the NICs has the address `35.198.81.101`.

Try changing it to: `.bindSecure(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 443, context)`

If that address definitely exists, also try `.bindSecure('35.198.81.101', 443, context)`

In general, the most common use case is to bind to all addresses (using `ANY...`), though often there is only one. Specifying ANY means that you aren't hard coding any addresses into your source code.

Another common case is to only bid to the loopback, so that only clients on the same machine can access the server, preventing any access over the network.

Comment: Yes, if I use `InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4` all work ok. But I need use by domain names, because I have sub domains with different certs and they should be isolated

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: The server's only ip address is `10.156.0.3`, so this is the only address to which it can bind. That looks like a private address, so wouldn't be accessible from the internet anyway. Are you planning to host this code somewhere publicly available eventually? You'll only be able to bind that address when the code is running on a machine with that address.

Comment: oh yes. I got it. Now I shoud solve new problem with binding to external IP on G Cloud... Thank you!